# How to verify Twitter oauth2.0 access token

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am doing authentication using twitter oauth 2.0 and using the issued access token as a way user can authenticate but the issue is I didn't find a way to verify the access token user is using for authentication is issued by my twitter client. Is there any way to get the client Id by which the twitter Oauth access token is issued so that I can verify it.

I want to get the client id by which the twitter Oauth access token is issued or a way by which I can verify the issued access token